# How can i use Api Keys that aren't google's

Tags: android, api

I'm trying to use an api key that isn't made by google, how can i add  it in my app without causing any mayhem to happen, Where do i add the api key if i'm only given the key itself not a file to use with it or a way to auto-implement(like firebase or google api).

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I make a constant java class and in there I put all my keys , so I need to change or add new keys I just put it in that class

```
public class Constants {

    //youtube api KEY
    public static final String YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "KSKMMSKVMKSMKVMSKMVKSfjj393fk";

}
```

Here is an class where to use the youtube api you import the keys from constants class and now you can use it

```
public class YoutubeVideo extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

String API_KEY = Constants.YOUTUBE_API_KEY;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube_video);


        // Initializing YouTube player view
        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);

}
```

Comment: But does it add the service which you are trying to reach?

Comment: I just add the api keys in there so I have them all in one place , I edited my post with an example of the class

Comment: I want them to be implemented into android studio, not just have them in a java class which doesn't use them

Comment: I added an example how I used the youtube keys in another class